# I want to make draggable div only with one area

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have draggable div with saving positions to database... I am moving picture but can I make only one area where i can click and move div or it need to be  whole div? Because Now i can click anywhere on div and move it  and I want to click on only one spot for moving div...

Comment: Please post your code and maybe also create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle).

Comment: can you share, what have you did so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `jqueryui` `draggable`,then you can use `handle` option.
check the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
  #draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #draggable p {
    cursor: move;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
      handle: "p"
    });

  });
</script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p class="ui-widget-header">handle</p>
</div>
```